# Abstract Class Java

Tags: java, class, equals, abstract, hashcode

I need to write abstract class, which looks like this.

```
public abstract class Value {

public abstract String toString();
public abstract Value add(Value v);
public abstract Value sub(Value v);
public abstract boolean eq(Value v);
public abstract boolean lte(Value v);
public abstract boolean gte(Value v);
public abstract boolean neq(Value v);
public abstract boolean equals(Object other);
public abstract int hashCode();
public abstract Value create(String s);
```

}

Now I need to make few classe, which inherit from that one. I started from Int class and implemented it like this:

```
public class Int extends Value {

int val;

public String toString() {
    String toStr = Integer.toString(val);
    return toStr;
}

public Int add(Value v) {
    Int result = new Int();
   if(v instanceof Int) {
        Int temp = (Int) v;
        result.val = val + temp.val;
    }

    return result;
}

public Int sub(Value v) {
    Int result = new Int();
    if(v instanceof Int) {
        Int temp = (Int) v;
        result.val = val - temp.val;
    }
    return result;
}

public boolean eq(Value o) {
    if(this == o) return true;
    if(this == null) return false;
    if(getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Int other = (Int) o;
    return toString() == other.toString();
}

public boolean lte(Value v) {
    if(v instanceof Int) {
        Int temp = (Int) v;
        return this.val < temp.val;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean gte(Value v) {
    if(v instanceof Int) { 
        Int temp = (Int) v;
        return this.val > temp.val;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean neq(Value v) {
    if(v instanceof Int) {
        Int temp = (Int) v;
        return !eq(temp);
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(this == o) return true;
    if(this == null) return false;
    if(getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Int other = (Int) o;
    return toString() == other.toString();
}

public int hashCode() {
    Integer hash = val;
    return hash.hashCode();
}

public Int create(String s) {
    val = Integer.parseInt(s);
    return this;
}
```

}

Everything is compiling and working, but I have no clue if my hashcode() function and equals() are good. Furthermore i want to use create() to make objects like this:

```
getInstance().create("1234");
```

Is my method also sufficient?

Comment: So you allow to add `Value` but you do nothing it it is not `Int` - kind of yyy wrong. Make it generic so int would only allow ints.

Comment: it is compiling? what is `result` in method `add` ?

Comment: `equals()` should compare state (not toString()):  `return val == other.val`

Comment: add is returning this.val + v.val. Everything is working.

Comment: `Value` is abstract but has not state and does not provide any implementation for any method - why not make it an interface?

Comment: I am not asking what is being returned, I am asking about the variable? field?  or whatever named `result` is. I can not find any `result` being declared in above code

Comment: Yea i fixed it, it should be Int

Comment: `if(this == null)` (in `equals()`), this is a pointless comparison. Maybe you meant to check if `o` is null.

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: and better use just `return Integer.hashCode(val);`   instead of creating an `Integer` just to get its hash code. The `create` method is a bit *strange* - being an instance method. Should be `static` and as such no need to e overriden.

Comment: In my opinion the create method should be static, and I don't understand where `getInstance` came from honestly.

Answer (score 1):

The `hashCode()` method is fine (although I'd add an `@Override` annotation, just to make the code easier to maintain and avoid mistakes), but the `equals(Object)` definitely isn't.

Following the logic you have in place, `==` isn't the right way to compare strings. You should use `equals` instead (see, e.g., [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/2422776)). In addition, as Joakim Danielson noted in the comments, `this` can never be `null` - you should check if `o` is `null` instead:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if(getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    Int other = (Int) o;
    return toString().equals(other.toString()); // Here!
}
```

But in all fairness, there's no reason to use `toString` - you could just compare the internal `val`:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if(getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    Int other = (Int) o;
    return val ==  other.val; // Here!
}
```

Comment: Again, why checking if `this` is null?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson nice catch, thanks for noticing. Copy-and-bugged from the OP :-) I've edited my answer to address this.

Answer (score 1):

> Everything is compiling and working, but I have no clue if my hashcode() function and equals() are good.

Your `equals()` should compare `int val` and not result of `toString()` of compared objects (`this.val == other.val`).

Your `hashCode()` looks good, though I would add `@Override` to it (same with `equals()`).

> Furthermore i want to use create() to make objects like this: `getInstance().create("1234");`

Looking at its implementation, it looks fine (i.e. would work according to your needs):

```
public Int create(String s) {
    val = Integer.parseInt(s);
    return this;
}
```

though I don't think you really want to use it with `getInstance()`. Simply `Int.create()` would be enough:

```
public static Int create(String s) {
    val = Integer.parseInt(s);
    return new Int(val);
}
```

Note that you would need a private constructor.

Also, as someone noted in the comments, consider using generics instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

First when you override Methods please do it with @Override Annotation. Then i would implement your equals method in another way. Just do return this.val == other.val instead of doing this.toString() == other.toString(). Your toString() method implementation is ok. Your hashCode is good as well. But please remove that create method. Use a constructor instead.

Comment: Thanks I will add annotations. I need to make that create function, but dont really know how. Its part of my homework. Later I have to create ArrayList<Value> and create specific value type

Comment: @GrzegorzKunc And what is the method supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Can I implement equals() method using eq() like this ?

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    Value compare = (Value) o;
    return eq(compare);
}
```